# How to check if the ul tag is empty using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to hide showing a div when the ul tag is empty
the html code is below,

```
<div class="menu">
    <header>
        <span class="title">title</span>
        <button>close</button>
    </header>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

from above html the ul tag has no li elements and i want to hide someother div. whereas if the code is like below where ul tag has one or more li elements within it i want to show the div.

```
<div class="menu">
    <header>
        <span class="title">title</span>
        <button>close</button>
    </header>
    <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can i check if ul tag is empty or not using javascript?
Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check for `innerHTML`, you can assign an identifier to `ul` (like `list` in below snippet) for easier access otherwise just use `querySelector`

```js
function isEmpty(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML.trim() == ""
}

console.log(isEmpty("list")); // logs `false` on console
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <header>
        <span class="title">title</span>
        <button>close</button>
    </header>
    <ul id="list">
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Without using id:

```js
function isEmpty(tag) {
  return document.querySelector(tag).innerHTML.trim() == ""
}

console.log(isEmpty("ul")); // logs `true` on console

console.log(isEmpty(".menu ul")); // logs `true` on console
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <header>
        <span class="title">title</span>
        <button>close</button>
    </header>
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but i dont want to introduce id for ul how can i do it with just css or queryselector.

Comment: This won't work if the empty element still contains a whitespace text node or an HTML comment.

Comment: @someuser2491 added snippet for `querySelector` example

Comment: thanks. instead of just using  selector "ul" i tried using document.querySelector('.menu ul).innerHTML.trim() == "" and it doesn't work.

Comment: @someuser2491 it should work without a problem, see the edited snippet, I've added the case you mentioned. It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use `querySelector()` for that:

```js
var ulElements = document.querySelector('.menu ul');
var displayVal = ulElements.children.length !== 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
document.querySelector('.show_hide').style.display = displayVal;
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <header>
    <span class="title">title</span>
    <button>close</button>
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="show_hide">show_hide</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for check tag have child or no

```
if( document.getElementById("test").innerHTML==""){
 //hasn't Child
}else{
 //has Child
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = $("#menu").find("li").length;
if (num > 1) {
  console.log(num);
}
```

use this Code